# React redux not fetching data from API

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi im new to redux and im trying to create a movie app using the API from [www.themoviedb.org](http://www.themoviedb.org). I am trying to display the popular movies and im sure the API link works since ive tested it in postman but i cant seem to figure out why redux doesnt pick up the data.

```
//action
import { FETCH_POPULAR } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchPopularMovies = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API}&language=en-US`
    )
    .then((response) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POPULAR,
        payload: response.data
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

---

```
//reducer
import { FETCH_POPULAR } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  popular: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POPULAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        popular: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Popular from "./Popular";


const FetchedPopular = (props) => {
  const { popular } = props;
  let content = "";

  content =
    popular.length > 0
      ? popular.map((item, index) => (
          <Popular key={index} popular={item} />
        
        ))
      : null;

  return <div className="fetched-movies">{content}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  popular: state.popular.popular,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FetchedPopular);
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import "../Styles.css";

const Popular = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="movie-container">
      <img
        className="poster"
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400/${props.poster_path}`}
      />
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popular;
```

I cant really tell what I'm missing can someone help?

Comment: can you console log `response.data` and check how your data stores in redux?

Comment: We cannot see when your action `fetchPopularMovies` is dispatched, can you post also code of dispatching of that action? Moreover, your `Popular` component is using `props.poster_path`, but you are not passing `poster_path` prop to your `Popular` component in `FetchedPopular`. You are passing `popular` prop instead. Shouldn't it be `props.popular.poster_path` then?

Comment: @lavor Hey sorry I'm very new to redux so I'm quite lost, the API fetches a list of movies and I wanted to map through the poster_path, if theres any suggestions on how I could make this happen I would be very greatful.  I added fetchPopularMovies next to mapStateToProps but im sure thats not correct lol..

Answer (score 0):

Next to `mapStateToProps` you need to create `mapDispatchToProps`. After that, you will be able to call your Redux action from your React component.
I suggest you the [mapDispatchToProps as an Object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) form. Then you need to use this `mapDispatchToProps` as the second parameter of your `connect` method.

When you will have your action mapped to your component, you need to call it somewhere. It is recommended to do it for example on a component mount. As your React components are Functional components, you need to do it in [React `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Popular from "./Popular";
import { fetchPopularMovies } from 'path_to_your_actions_file'

const FetchedPopular = (props) => {
  const { popular } = props;
  let content = "";

  useEffect(()=> {
    // call your mapped action (here it is called once on component mount due the empty dependency array of useEffect hook)
    props.fetchPopularMovies();
  }, [])

  content =
    popular.length > 0
      ? popular.map((item, index) => (
          <Popular key={index} popular={item} />
        
        ))
      : null;

  return <div className="fetched-movies">{content}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  popular: state.popular.popular,
});

// create mapDispatchToProps
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchPopularMovies
}

// use mapDispatchToProps as the second parameter of your `connect` method.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FetchedPopular);
```

Moreover, as I wrote above in my comment, your `Popular` does not have the prop `poster_path` but it has the prop `popular` which probably has the property `poster_path`.

```js
import React from "react";
import "../Styles.css";

const Popular = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="movie-container">
      <img
        className="poster"
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400/${props.popular.poster_path}`}
      />
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popular;
```